# LabVIEW using C DLL using OpenCV DLL

Tags: opencv, dll, labview

I am developping a C++ DLL with C wrapper to be able to use it in different languages. For now, I can use it in C# and Python, and before to find how to do it on MATLAB, I have to find the way to read it on LabVIEW.

I am using Visual Studio, so I installed openCV on `C:\`, added the `include` directory and the `.lib` files to my project, created a new environment variable, and in my DLL I use it using `#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>`. All this in 32 bits of course because LabVIEW is very bad on 64 bits.

But, when I create a node with "Call Library Function Node", after setting inputs/outputs, I click on OK and LabVIEW tell me it didn't find the dll associated to OpenCV.

[image]
[image]

I am a total newbie on this field (DLL) so I am not aware of what I have to check or add in LabVIEW.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed this issue. I only had to copy/paste the DLL files of OpenCV on the same directory of the LabVIEW library.

Comment: Can you copy the open CV DLLs on your target device instead?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to use Open CV static libs instead of DLL. You can download OpenCV source from opencv.org and download latest version of CMake from cmake.org. CMake will generate Visual Studio solution and other required files from platform-independent source files. So you will be able to change Visual Studio project target from DLL to static LIB and build static libs of Open CV on your own PC.

Comment: I am sorry but I have 0 experience in CMake. For now I am adding to my C++ project the lib files so for me I am aleady using the static libs.

Comment: lib files for enabling DLL usage and static libs (also *.lib files) are not the same. As far as I see from your question, an application, that you have performed in NI LabView calls your DLL, then your DLL tries to call OpenCV 2.4.1 DLL from working directory of your LabView application. The second possible solution in your case can be adding path to Open CV DLL folder in PATH variable in Windows Control Panel.